# "Сообщество Stack Overflow на русском" - это только часть сообщества "Stack Overflow" без языковых различий?

Tags: поддержка

"Сообщество Stack Overflow на русском" -  это только часть сообщества "Stack Overflow" без языковых различий?

Comment: `без языковых различий?` - ну вроде же "на русском"

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно.

Comment: Да, это часть большой сети StackExchange в которой множество Q&A сайтов

Comment: @Grundy, [SE же уже SO](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1312/178988)?

Comment: @Qwertiy компания, но не [сеть сообществ](https://stackexchange.com/).