# Не показывается плашка о возможном дубликате

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, дубликаты

["Сообщество Stack Overflow на русском" - это только часть сообщества "Stack Overflow" без языковых различий?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6390/178988)

Почему-то наверху нет плашки о предложенном дубликате.
By some reason panel about possible duplicate is not shown.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: а разве она не показывается только у автора вопроса?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Квертий спалился на сокпупете :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, я что-то перепутал и думал, что модераторам тоже должна показываться. Ты прав.

Comment: А дать самоответ? Или привлечь первого комментатора? :)

Comment: @alexolut, так я ему коммент написал - пусть постит)

Comment: Вопрос ради вопроса?

Comment: Да ладно, что заминусовали-то.

Comment: @NickVolynkin это ж Мета ... тут и на *** послать могут. P.S. MSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта плашка показывается только автору вопроса и не показывается модераторам.

Comment: А если модератор - автор вопроса? :)

Comment: @alexolut, да: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6233/178988

Comment: Я к тому, что в ответе для педантичности это можно уточнить. Хотя это уже наверное слишком :)